# DetailView разбиение на столбцы, использование

Tags: php, yii2, views

Здравствуйте.

Для отображения данных в представление использую DetailView. Фреймворк Yii2, Бд - MySQL.

Получилось вывести тестовые данные строчками. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код представления:

```
use kartik\detail\DetailView;

 $attributes = [
'first_name',
'last_name',
'patronymic',
'english_first_name',
'english_last_name',
'gender',
'birthday',
'address_line_1',
'address_line_2',
'company_name',
'postal_code',
'city',
'fax_number',
'mobile_phone',
'work_phone',
'home_phone',
'email',
];

echo DetailView::widget([
'model'=>$model,
'condensed'=>true,
'hover'=>true,
'mode'=>DetailView::MODE_VIEW,
'panel'=>[
    'heading'=>'Анкета # ' . $model->id,
    'type'=>DetailView::TYPE_INFO,
],
'attributes'=>$attributes
]);
?>
```

Как сделать разбиение как в примере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В исходном коде примера есть строчки:

```
  $attributes = [
...
    'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute'=>'id', 
            'label'=>'Book #',
            'displayOnly'=>true,
            'valueColOptions'=>['style'=>'width:30%']
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'book_code', 
            'format'=>'raw', 
            'value'=>'<kbd>'.$model->book_code.'</kbd>',
            'valueColOptions'=>['style'=>'width:30%'], 
            'displayOnly'=>true
        ],
    ],
  ...
```

Но при попытке сделать тоже самое:

```
$attributes = [
'columns' => [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'patronymic',
    'english_first_name',
    'english_last_name',
    'gender',
    'birthday'
],

'address_line_1',
'address_line_2',
'company_name',
'postal_code',
'city',
'fax_number',
'mobile_phone',
'work_phone',
'home_phone',
'email',
 ];
```

Выдает ошибку:

> The attribute configuration requires the "attribute" element to determine the value and display label.

Как исправить данную ошибку и разбить на колонки?

Впервые взялся за DetailView, но он необходим.

Заранее спасибо за ответы и советы. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так. Немного разобрался.

Для того, чтобы сделать в колонку что-то, нужно в атрибутах 
сделать отдельный массив, и там уже прописывать колонку.

```
$attributes = [
    ['columns' =>[
     [
        'group'=>true,
        'label'=>'Personal info',
        'displayOnly'=>true,
        'groupOptions'=>['class'=>'text-left']
     ],
     [
        'group'=>true,
        'label'=>'Contact info',
        'displayOnly'=>true,
        'groupOptions'=>['class'=>'text-left']
     ]
    ]
  ],
   ['columns' =>
     [
          [
         'attribute'=>'first_name',
        'valueColOptions'=>['style'=>'width:30%']
          ],
          [
        'attribute'=>'mobile_phone',
        'valueColOptions'=>['style'=>'width:30%']
          ]
      ],
   ]
 ];
```

Вот так это будет выглядеть на странице:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталось решить проблему, чтобы было все в одну линию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решу, дополню ответ.

PS. Чтобы столбцы были ровные, я подгонял их через параметры, у меня получилось:

```
    [
        'group'=>true,
        'label'=>'Personal info',
        'groupOptions'=>['class'=>'text-left','style'=>'width:50.1%']
    ],
    [
        'group'=>true,
        'label'=>'Contact info',
        'groupOptions'=>['class'=>'text-left','style'=>'width:49.9%']
    ]
```

Именно groupOptions с style отвечают за это.

Надеюсь, это кому-то поможет. )